# If .length is > for a select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
function Player(username, lvl, exp, expNeeded, nextLevel, gold, hp, atk, def, spd) {
    var self = this;
    this.username = username;
    this.lvl = lvl;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.nextLevel = nextLevel;
    this.expNeeded = expNeeded;
    this.gold = gold;
    this.fullLife = hp;
    this.hp = hp;
    this.atk = atk;
    this.def = def;
    this.spd = spd;
    this.implement = function() {
        $('#user').text(this.username).addClass('playerName').data('player', self)
        $('#username').text("Username: " + this.username);
        $('#lvl').text("Level: " + this.lvl);
        $('#exp').text("Experience: " + this.exp);
        $('#expNeeded').text("Experience Needed: " + this.expNeeded);
        $('#gold').text("Gold: " + this.gold);
        $('#hp').text("HP: " + this.fullLife);
        $('#attack').text("Attack: " + this.atk);
        $('#defense').text("Defense: " + this.def);
        $('#speed').text("Speed: " + this.spd);
        $('#nextLevel').text("Next Level: " + this.nextLevel);
    }
    this.implement();
}
var newPlayer = new Player(prompt("What is your username?"), 1, 0, 10, 10, 0, 10, 2, 1, 1);
playerEl = $('.playerName');
player = playerEl.data('player');

function Monster(name, exp, gold, hp, atk, def, spd) {

  var self = this;
 this.name = name;
 this.exp = exp;
  this.gold = gold;
  this.fullLife = hp;
  this.hp = hp;
  this.atk = atk;
  this.def = def;
  this.spd = spd;
  // Method definition
  this.implement = function() {
   var monsterList = document.getElementById('monsterList');
    var opt = document.createElement('OPTION'); // Creating option
    opt.innerText = this.name; // Setting innertText attribute
    $(opt).data('monster', self)
    monsterList.appendChild(opt); // appending option to select element
  }
  this.len = this.name.length;
  this.playerDamage = 0;
  this.playerDam = function () {
   if(player.atk <= this.def) {
     self.playerDamage = player.atk - 1;
      return self.playerDamage;
    }
    else {
   self.playerDamage = Math.round((player.atk - self.def) * (2 - Math.random()));
    return self.playerDamage;
    }
  }
  this.monsterDamage = 0;
  this.monsterDam = function() {
      if(this.atk <= player.def) {
          self.monsterDamage = monster.atk - 1;
          return self.monsterDamage;
      }
    else {
        self.monsterDamage = Math.round((self.atk - player.def) * (2 - Math.random()));
        return self.monsterDamage;
    }
  }
  // Method execution
  this.implement();
}

var fly = new Monster("fly", 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1);
var mouse = new Monster("mouse", 2, 3, 10, 2, 1, 2);
var rat = new Monster("rat", 4, 5, 20, 4, 2, 2);
var rabidChihuahua = new Monster("chihuahua", 6, 8, 35, 6, 1, 4);
var bulldog = new Monster("bulldog", 10, 14, 60, 10, 4, 1);
var wolf = new Monster("Wolf", 15, 18, 65, 12, 3, 6);
var vampie = new Monster("Vampire", 20, 23, 100, 12, 5, 4);
var werewolf = new Monster("Werewolf", 25, 29, 100, 14, 3, 9);
var giantSlime = new Monster("Giant Slime", 31, 38, 200, 7, 15, 1);
var babyDragon = new Monster("Baby Dragon", 39, 50, 150, 16, 9, 5);
var orc = new Monster("Orc", 50, 64, 220, 10, 12, 4);
var succubi = new Monster("Succubi", 61, 80, 190, 21, 8, 12);
var elderDragon = new Monster("Elder Dragon", 75, 100, 300, 21, 15, 8);
var sanaan = new Monster("Sanaan", 150, 500, 500, 55, 45, 30);


monsterEl = $('#monsterList option:selected');
monster = monsterEl.data('monster');
$('#battleButton').click(function() {
 //playerDam();
    var round = 0;

  $('#dam').empty();
  $('#monsterdam').empty();
  while(monster.hp > 0 && player.hp > 0 && round < 20) {
      $('#monsterdam').append("</p>The " + $('#monsterList').val() + " has hit you for " + monster.monsterDam() + " damage</p>");
      player.hp -= monster.monsterDam();
   $('#dam').append("</p>You have hit the " + $('#monsterList').val() + " for " + monster.playerDam() + " damage</p>");
    monster.hp -= monster.playerDam();
    round +=1;
        if(round >=20) {
            $('#monsterdam').append("</p>The battle has timed out</p>");
            $('#dam').append("</p>The battle has timed out</p>");
        }
  }
  if(monster.hp <= 0){
  $('#dam').append("<p>You have defeated the " + $('#monsterList').val() + ", you have received " + monster.exp + " experience and " + monster.gold + " gold!</p>");
    monster.hp = monster.fullLife;
    player.hp = player.fullLife;
    player.exp += monster.exp;
    player.gold += monster.gold;
    player.nextLevel -= monster.exp;
    player.implement();
    if(player.exp >= player.expNeeded) {
        lvlUp();
    }
}
if(player.hp <= 0){
$('#monsterdam').append("<p>The " + $('#monsterList').val() + " has defeated you!</p>");
  monster.hp = monster.fullLife;
  player.hp = player.fullLife;
}
});

var lvlUp = function() {
    player.expNeeded += player.expNeeded + player.lvl * player.lvl;
    player.nextLevel = player.expNeeded - player.exp;
    player.fullLife += player.lvl * 5 + (2 * player.lvl);
    player.lvl += 1;
    player.atk += 1;
    player.def += 1;
    player.spd += 1;
}

if(monster.len > 8) {
    $('select').css({
        "font-size": "12px"
    });
}
else {
    $('select').css({
        "font-size": "18px"
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

#stats {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(98, 39, 39, 0.6);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(24%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#8f3939', GradientType=1 );
}

#stats li {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#stats ul {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#intro {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-family: "Cabin", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#stats ul:not(.firstul) {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#nav {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(98, 39, 39, 0.6);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(24%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#8f3939', GradientType=1 );
}

#user {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: rgba(156, 48, 48, 1);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.5px black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px darkred,
                       1px 1px 0px #000,
                       3px 3px 0px #000,
                       4px 4px 2px #000;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: .8;
    color: #a3a3a3;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #111,
                       2px 2px 4px #000;
}

#nav li:hover {
    color: #e0e0e0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222,
                       2px 2px 3px #333,
                       3px 3px 0px #000;
}

#nav li:not(.first) {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}

select:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
ul a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

select {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #941919;
  color: #941919;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left:450px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
}


option {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    background-color: #000;
}

main {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid rgba(98, 39, 39, .6);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(24%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 24%, rgba(143,57,57,0.5) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#8f3939', GradientType=1);
}

#battleButton {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #941919;
  color: #941919;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#help, #noHelp {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-color: #941919;
  color: #941919;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  float: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#help {
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 495px;
}

#noHelp {
    margin: auto;
}

#dam {
  color: #941919;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 40%;
  min-width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 40px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#monsterdam {
  color: #941919;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 40%;
  min-width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin: 40px;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
  <body>
<header id="stats">
    <ul class="firstul">
        <li id="username"></li>
        <li id="lvl"></li>
        <li id="exp"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li id="expNeeded"></li>
        <li id="nextLevel"></li>
        <li id="hp"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li id="attack"></li>
        <li id="defense"></li>
        <li id="speed"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li id="gold"></li>
        <li id="items">Items: </li>
    </ul>
</header>
<header id="nav">
    <h1 id="user"></h1>
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li class="first">Home</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Battle</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Profile</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Inventory</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Help</li></a>
    </ul>
</header>
<main>
    <div>
    <select id="monsterList"></select>

    <button id="battleButton">Battle</button>
    </div>
    <div id="dam"></div>
    <div id="monsterdam"></div>
</main>

    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
```

I have a select menu and I want to change the font-size to be smaller if the word for the option selected is longer than a certain amount of characters. I've tried multiple ways of doing this and nothing works. Here is my most recent attempt.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbxu0p2d/)

```
if(monster.len > 8) {
    $('select').css({
        "font-size": "12px"
    });
}
else {
    $('select').css({
        "font-size": "18px"
    });
}
```

Comment: This code is working, but `monster.len == 3`, so always set `18px`. At least in your fiddle. Will be better if you explain what you need. If you want to avoid overflowing in the name, maybe you need something like `text-overflow: ellipsis`. Explain better or this question should be closed as offtopic (questions seeking "why isn't this code working?" are offtopic in stackoverflow if you don't provide a working example)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude is correct, it is changing on page load to 18px, which you can see inline on the select tag, but you don't have this logic inside a jquery change event for the select tag.

Comment: When you click on the select menu and select one of the other options (Elder Dragon is the longest) then monster.len is no longer = to 3.

Comment: right, but you're not listening to what my comment is suggesting.

Comment: @Shniper True, but the snippet you posted in the question is only executed on page load, not after changing the selected value.

Comment: How can I target only the selected option so that the font size is changed inside the select button but not in the dropdown menu itself (hard to explain)

Comment: @Shniper check my answer below

Answer (score 3):

Just glancing through your code, it looks like you are not binding to any change event on your select. The if statement runs just the one time on page load, checking the length, which is probably not what you want. You need to bind to change, check the length of the selected monster, then act on it.

Comment: If you had looked through my code you would see that I define .len inside the object creator. When I use .length it doesn't work

Comment: @Shniper, we're trying to help you so please mind your tone.  In fact, you should edit your code down to the bare minimum before you post here so that it's easier for folks to help.

Comment: Being rude was not my intent, and the reason I have the full code is because whenever I don't post it I always get asked for it

Comment: Just glancing through your code, it looks like you are not binding to any change event on your select. The `if` statement runs just the one time, checking the length, which is probably not what you want. You need to bind to change, check the length of the selected monster, then act on it.

Comment: Nobody here will ask you for your full code. Will ask you for a working example, that's not the same. A working example must be Minimal, Complete and Verifiable: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```js
$('#monsterList').on('change', function() {

  if ($('option:selected', this).text().length > 8) {
    $('select').css({
      "font-size": "12px"
    });
    $('select option').css({
      "font-size": "12px"
    });
  } else {

    $('select').css({
      "font-size": "18px"
    });
    $('select option').css({
      "font-size": "12px"
    });

  }

}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="monsterList">
  <option>fly</option>
  <option>wolf</option>
  <option>chihuahua</option>
  <option>fladaday</option>
  <option>Vampire</option>
  <option>Giant Slime</option>
  <option>Orc</option>
  <option>Sanaan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your check only runs on what is the default selected option when the page loads. The code will not run when you change the value in the select. You would need to trigger that chunk of code  when the select element is changed.

So wrap the

```
$("select").on("change", function () {
    /* your code */
}).trigger("change");  //so it runs when initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

Am i correct if you want the `<option>` tag's to have different styles depending on your monsters name length?

```
$('#monsterList option').each(function(){
        if($(this).html().length > 8){
        $(this).css('font-size', '12px');
      }
    })
```

This code will change the `font` if the name is longer then 8 characters in the `select` field. Your code is kinda wrecked, so i didnt try to use your own variables because of all the spagetthi, but this does the job.

working script: https://jsfiddle.net/sbxu0p2d/4/

Answer (score 1):

If you move this line:

```
var elderDragon = new Monster("Elder Dragon", 75, 100, 300, 21, 15, 8);
```

before this line:

```
var fly = new Monster("fly", 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1);
```

Then you'll notice that your `font` does get loaded in the way you want it, so the .len functionality you implemented works. As stated above all you need now is to bind a `event listener` to the `dropdownbox` and then check the selected value in the same way as you were already doing.